# Likes on Facebook Posts Pagination

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, pagination

I want to count the number of likes (and comments) on a Facebook post. But when there's more than 25 likes on a post, the results are paginated like that:

```
stdClass Object ( [data] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 802020049912534 [name] => Sagar Lama ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 590020061101130 [name] => Sheguey Squaad ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 696207733846316 [name] => Ossama Barcalona ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1901218896769448 [name] => Gab Alviola ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 407069606150738 [name] => Thongloy Thichanon ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 947084195347741 [name] => Thomas VujiÄ‡ ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1614068872196230 [name] => à¹€à¸žà¸·à¹ˆà¸­à¸™à¸à¸¹à¹€à¸ˆà¹‡à¸š à¸Šà¸µà¸§à¸´à¸•à¸¡à¸¶à¸‡à¸ˆà¸š ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1431328280529413 [name] => Ali-Bilal Dernek ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 855095404568872 [name] => Henry Feng ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 937460179628960 [name] => Rex Lu ) [10] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1627484497506023 [name] => RÃ¶bÃ«rt GÃ¤rÄÃ¯Ã¢ ) [11] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 971640236220159 [name] => Reyjoel Jimeno ) [12] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1644471585776456 [name] => Og Catwalk ) [13] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1652037021731712 [name] => Rafik Benchibane ) [14] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 499561140196412 [name] => Lizy Smith ) [15] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 10207169299621544 [name] => Ngai Lam ) [16] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 505507699598850 [name] => Ã‹lloÃ¯ Gonzalez Sanchez ) [17] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 802078276575586 [name] => Armando Sanchez ) [18] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 10205977306769395 [name] => Fredy Santizo ) [19] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 811409772291367 [name] => Malik Davis ) [20] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 842376069172521 [name] => Isak Renee Martinez ) [21] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 915675738506394 [name] => Kimora Stephens Davis ) [22] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 916531748393520 [name] => Isabel Averill ) [23] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 941049645918044 [name] => Mathias Tenezaca Mendez ) [24] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1452189318420627 [name] => Andrew Hernandez ) ) [paging] => stdClass Object ( [cursors] => stdClass Object ( [after] => MTQ1MjE4OTMxODQyMDYyNw== [before] => ODAyMDIwMDQ5OTEyNTM0 ) [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/15087023444_10153196470723445/likes?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&limit=25&after=MTQ1MjE4OTMxODQyMDYyNw%3D%3D ) )
```

How can I count likes and comments on a given post without asking the Facebook API too much. I'm using the PHP SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use paging to go through all Likes, or you can use the summary parameter to get a total count:

```
/post-id?fields=likes.summary(true)
```

Part of the response:

```
"summary": {
    "total_count": 393,
    "can_like": true,
    "has_liked": false
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can i use the paging in an efficient and simple way?

Comment: use a recursive function, for example